# jQuery ajax POST is sending an additional GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am just starting with jQuery and I am trying to do a $.post request, but I am getting a post AND a get (see log below). I have searched a lot and only found cases where they were calling an ajax function twice.

My case is a dynamic table of forms where I want to send an ajax POST when a single form is submitted.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form.newguess', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).serialize());
    $.post("game", $(this).serialize());
});
```

Here is my JSP:

```
...<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="player" items="${players}">
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell"><p>${player.key}</p></td>
            <td class="guesscell">
                <p>${player.value}</p>
            </td>
            <td class="inputcell">
                <form class="newguess" action="game" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="guess" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="player" value="${player.key}"/>
                    <input type="submit" value=">"/>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

And here is the log from my server:

```
23:32:41,617 INFO (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) POST - Game
23:32:41,696 INFO (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) GET - Game
```

I have tried to remove the $.post and then I don't receive anything, so it is definitely the $.post.

Any ideas are welcome, it must be a very dumb mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: how many times do you get that alert? Once or twice?

Comment: I get the alert only once.

Comment: Can you change $(this).serialize() into an anonymous function and add a console.log inside it to see how many times it's getting called?

Comment: What happens if you remove the post method from the form and instead of using a submit button, just use a button?

Comment: errr... sorry @joshboley I am just starting with javascript, I don't know how to make this anonymous function. Anyways, I don't think it is being called twice because there is not any other javascript in this project. Could it have something to do with the <form action=.. method=.. ?

Comment: @entiendoNull since I am capturing the submit event, if I replace the submit button for a regular button, I don't think my code would work. I may be wrong here, I don't know how to attach the event handler to a dynamic table of forms..

Comment: I would just use the form to simply serialize my form elements to a string handy to send and retrieve... but trigger the AJAX request by some other event, e.g. just a normal button click :)

Comment: it is normal after post the response is got from server which is GET

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, whaaaaat? Not as far as I'm concerned...

Comment: yes @entiendoNull if you see your ajax call via fiddler you will notice that after POST a GET is done what i have noticed

Comment: Just made one.. my firebug will only display the ajax method being used.

Comment: yep, I am with @entiendoNull on this one, the GET after the POST is not normal. I am investigating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I knew it had to be something dumb.

This is my code on the server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/game", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postPlayerGuess(@RequestParam("player") String playerName,
          @RequestParam("guess") String guess, Model model) {
    System.out.println("POST");
    gameService.setGuess(myself.getGameName(), playerName, newGuess);
    return "redirect:/game";
}
```

Notice that `redirect:/game` at the end? yep, that it was. I was redirecting the response, so the client made another GET request.

Sorry guys, you couldn't have solved this one without the code on the server, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a normal button instead of

```
<input type="submit" value=">"/>
```

use

```
<input type="button" value=">" onclick="yourFunction"/>
```

Maybe thats why it is sending two times, one from jquery and another from the DOM (?)

Comment: I think the `event.preventDefault();` should prevent the post from the DOM. I also tried to remove the `$.post` line entirely, but then I don't receive anything, so both logs on the server are caused by the `$.post`. But I will try using a regular button as you suggest and reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to, you have put your form in loop. So that every first iteration your mentioned form method will post but after that all form will have get request by default.

You need to generate unique "name" for every form . To avoid multiple GET/POST request .

Comment: nope sorry, it was `redirect:/game` on the server, which was instructing the client to do a GET afterwards. I removed it and now it is working fine.